# Is there a way to export only newly created/modified users from LDAP everyhour?

Tags: ldap, servicenow

I am trying to create a LDAP filter that brings in only the newly created/updated users.  I am planning to schedule this job to run every hour.  So, I shall have the newly created/updated users from AD to servicenow every hour.

I tried to use `(modifytimestamp)` method, but the Zulu date is hardcoded.  How to make it filter every hour?  I mean, the filter should be `(modifyTimeStamp >=(now - 1hr))`

```
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(!(renaccountsuspended=1))(modifyTimeStamp>=20190418123800Z))
```

Comment: Have you looked at using the DirSync control [Polling for Changes Using the DirSync Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/polling-for-changes-using-the-dirsync-control)?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not recommended practice, but you could use a scheduled script execution job to update the filter on your ldap ou config every day in conjunction with the whenChanged ldap attribute. Something like this maybe (untested):

**Scheduled job every day:**

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('ldap_ou_config');
gr.get('name','Users'); //or whatever your filter is uniquely named
var curFilter = gr.filter;
//(&(objectClass=person)(whenChanged>=20190704000000.0Z)(sn=*)(!(objectClass=computer))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)));
var curDate = curFilter.substr(curFilter.indexOf('whenChanged>=') + 13,8);
var today = new GlideDateTime().toString().split(' ')[0].split('-').join('');
curFilter = curFilter.replace(curDate, today);
gr.filter = curFilter;
gr.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the LDAP listener.

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-platform-administration/page/integrate/ldap/task/t_EnableAListener.html)